# Fixing eigenvector signs for eigen() or svd()

Tags: r

Is there a way to fix the signs of the eigenvectors as returned by eigen or svd? princomp() has a fix_sign argument, which when set to TRUE, forces the first element of each eigenvector column to be positive. Does eigen or svd have something similar?

eigen and svd are preferred because I want to directly work with X'X, without scaling, centering etc.

I know that it is possible to replicate this effects of this by specifying X'X as a covmat argument to princomp, but this is a little unwieldy.

```
set.seed(123)
X <- data.frame(
  x1 = arima.sim(list(ar = 0.5), n = 100),
  x2 = arima.sim(list(ar = 0.5), n = 100),
  x3 = arima.sim(list(ar = 0.5), n = 100)
) |> as.matrix()

eigen(t(X) %*% X)$vectors
svd(t(X) %*% X)
# This below approach works, but is a little unwieldy
princomp(covmat = t(X) %*% X, fix_sign = TRUE)
```

Comment: Just multiply each column by the sign of the first element in that column.  `e <- eigen(t(X) %*% X); vecs <- e$vecs;
vecs_fix <- vecs %*% diag(sign(vecs[1, ]))`

Comment: Yeah I figured that was a straightforward way to do it, annoying that eigen() and svd() don't have any built in arguments to do so.